# Quantlib: Vol surface, different strike levels for different tenors

Tags: python, quantlib

I want to build an implied vol surface w/ Quantlib. I notice BlackVarianceSurface class can take in a strike list, an expiration list and a volMatrix as input. However, what if I want to set different strikes for different tenors?
In the below example, how should I set strikes for 2013/12/20 as [1645, 1650, 1655], and for 2014/1/17 as [1650, 1660, 1670]?

Thanks for helping out.

```
import Quantlib as ql

referenceDate = ql.Date(30, 9, 2013)
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = referenceDate
calendar = ql.TARGET()
dayCounter = ql.ActualActual()
strikes = [1650.0, 1660.0, 1670.0]
expirations = [ql.Date(20, 12, 2013), ql.Date(17, 1, 2014), ql.Date(21, 3, 2014)]
volMatrix = ql.Matrix(len(strikes), len(expirations))

volMatrix[0][0] = .15640
volMatrix[0][1] = .15433
volMatrix[0][2] = .16079

volMatrix[1][0] = .15343
volMatrix[1][1] = .15240
volMatrix[1][2] = .15804

volMatrix[2][0] = .15128
volMatrix[2][1] = .14888
volMatrix[2][2] = .15512

volatilitySurface = ql.BlackVarianceSurface(referenceDate, calendar, expirations, strikes, volMatrix, dayCounter)
volatilitySurface.enableExtrapolation()

volatilitySurface.blackVol(0.5, 1650.0)
```